# URL redirection to domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect a paginated php url to my index page using .htaccess.

For example I want this paginated urls:

```
domain.com/blue.php?id=3
domain.com/blue.php?id=3&pageNumber=2
domain.com/blue.php?id=3&pageNumber=3
```

etc

to redirect to the main index page:

```
domain.com
```

Comment: it's just a url. look for whatever query string args you want to match, and redirect if they're found.

Comment: Why do you want to do this redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Redirect permanent domain.com/blue.php?id=3 domain.com
Redirect permanent domain.com/blue.php?id=3&pageNumber=2 domain.com
Redirect permanent domain.com/blue.php?id=3&pageNumber=3 domain.com
order deny,allow
```

You can also use this generator
http://www.htaccesseditor.com/en.shtml

Comment: Then you also try to use the www before your domain

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=3($|&)
RewriteRule ^blue\.php$ / [L,R]
```